# Permanently hide Android Status Bar

Tags: android, root, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to hide the system Status Bar on an Android 4.4 device. This is for a kiosk-mode where my app will be the only app ever run on the device. The target device for now is a 2013 Nexus 7.

The device is rooted, and I've been able to completely remove the bottom Navigation Bar with some info from [this post](http://thebitplague.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/kiosk-mode-on-the-nexus-7/).

For the top Status Bar, everything I have tried only hides the bar temporarily. If my users motion down at the top of the screen, the status bar reappears. I don't want to allow them to see the time, get to settings or even see notifications.

Posts I've found and already tried:

- [Hide System Bar in Tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605266/hide-system-bar-in-tablets/12605313)
- [Permanently hide navigation bar on activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713845/permanently-hide-navigation-bar-on-activity)
- [Hide status bar on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860118/hide-status-bar-on-android)
- [Disable/Hide status bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942288/disable-hide-status-bar-in-android)

Any suggestions?

Ideally, I'd love to be able to edit build.prop to do this, since I'm already doing that for the navigation bar, and could do this at the same time. I'm trying to not have to build my own android image.

**Update:**

After some more work, this seems to depend somewhat on the exact build of android, or the device its running on.

Some devices, such as the Nexus series I've been working with allow the user to swipe to make the bar reappear.

However, I've recently tried this on a Verizon Eclipse, and the bar does not reappear, which is what I was looking for.

I'm still looking for a better solution to target all devices, but it will probably come down to creating my own build of android.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm struggling with the same issue for a game. Cheers.

Comment: Android "L" will be just the thing for you: http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/07/08/android-l-spotlight-task-locking-enables-strict-focus-apps-enterprise-education-kiosks/

Answer (score 28):

We could not prevent the status appearing in full screen mode in kitkat devices, so made a hack which still suits the requirement ie block the status bar from expanding.

For that to work, the app was not made full screen. We put a overlay over status bar and consumed all input events. It prevented the status from expanding.

***note:***

- customViewGroup is custom class which extends any
  layout(frame,relative layout etc) and consumes touch event.
- to consume touch event override the onInterceptTouchEvent method of
  the view group and return true

**Updated**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

[customViewGroup implementation](https://gist.github.com/sarme/7e4dc90e2478ade310e6)
Code :

```
WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));

WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|

            // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |

            // Draws over status bar
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;

    localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    localLayoutParams.height = (int) (50 * getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
    localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;

    customViewGroup view = new customViewGroup(this);

    manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Helped us. Thank you.

Comment: **To remove I added this code part under the onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)**  `if (isPermissionedEnabled) {
                try {
                    manager.removeViewImmediate(view);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e("ERROR ON INTERCEPT", ex.toString());
                }
                isPermissionedEnabled = false;
            }`

Answer (score 21):

I did try the workaround provided by @gonglong, but I wasn't happy with the result because of a flash in the UI as the workaround kicked in.

Instead, I was able to do this as root:

```
settings put secure user_setup_complete 0
```

I think on a normal device, this would cause the initial device setup to start, but on my devices, I've removed that APK from system so that doesn't happen.

This isn't documented anywhere I can find, but has a nice effect, where the top settings UI can't be dragged down. The notifications area can still be dragged down.

Another setting that I found useful was:

```
settings put global device_provisioned 0
```

This hides the Airplane Mode and Silent Mode options from the Power menu, which is an added bonus for my application.

There might be more side effects, but I've yet to find any that matter to me.

### Full List

This list was taken from a Nexus 7 2013 LTE running brand new Android 4.4.3 (KTU84L). The number in square brackets is the value when I pulled the db file, which was after basic setup device setup and enabling developer/USB, but before making any other changes in settings

This file was found at `data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db`

Note: Some URLS required adding an extra space character to bypass SO filters

#### `system` namespace

- volume_music [11]
- volume_ring [5]
- volume_system [7]
- volume_voice [4]
- volume_alarm [6]
- volume_notification [5]
- volume_bluetooth_sco [7]
- mode_ringer_streams_affected [174]
- mute_streams_affected [46]
- vibrate_when_ringing [0]
- dim_screen [1]
- dtmf_tone_type [0]
- hearing_aid [0]
- tty_mode [0]
- screen_brightness [87]
- screen_brightness_mode [1]
- window_animation_scale [1.0]
- transition_animation_scale [1.0]
- accelerometer_rotation [1]
- haptic_feedback_enabled [1]
- notification_light_pulse [1]
- dtmf_tone [1]
- sound_effects_enabled [1]
- lockscreen_sounds_enabled [1]
- pointer_speed [0]
- alarm_alert [content://media/internal/audio/media/11]
- notification_sound [content://media/internal/audio/media/27]
- ringtone [content://media/internal/audio/media/35]
- next_alarm_formatted []
- radio.data.stall.recovery.action [0]
- screen_off_timeout [30000]

#### `global` namespace

- airplane_mode_on [0]
- airplane_mode_radios [cell,bluetooth,wifi,nfc,wimax]
- airplane_mode_toggleable_radios [bluetooth,wifi,nfc]
- auto_time [1]
- auto_time_zone [1]
- stay_on_while_plugged_in [0]
- wifi_sleep_policy [2]
- mode_ringer [2]
- package_verifier_enable [1]
- wifi_networks_available_notification_on [1]
- bluetooth_on [0]
- cdma_cell_broadcast_sms [1]
- data_roaming [0]
- mobile_data [1]
- netstats_enabled [1]
- install_non_market_apps [0]
- usb_mass_storage_enabled [1]
- wifi_max_dhcp_retry_count [9]
- wifi_display_on [0]
- lock_sound [/system/media/audio/ui/Lock.ogg]
- unlock_sound [/system/media/audio/ui/Unlock.ogg]
- power_sounds_enabled [1]
- low_battery_sound [/system/media/audio/ui/LowBattery.ogg]
- dock_sounds_enabled [0]
- desk_dock_sound [/system/media/audio/ui/Dock.ogg]
- desk_undock_sound [/system/media/audio/ui/Undock.ogg]
- car_dock_sound [/system/media/audio/ui/Dock.ogg]
- car_undock_sound [/system/media/audio/ui/Undock.ogg]
- wireless_charging_started_sound [/system/media/audio/ui/WirelessChargingStarted.ogg]
- dock_audio_media_enabled [1]
- set_install_location [0]
- default_install_location [0]
- emergency_tone [0]
- call_auto_retry [0]
- preferred_network_mode [9]
- subscription_mode [1]
- low_battery_sound_timeout [3600000]
- wifi_watchdog_on [1]
- audio_safe_volume_state [1]
- send_action_app_error [1]
- web_autofill_query_url [http:// android.clients.google.com/proxy/webautofill]
- sms_short_codes_content_url [http://www.gstatic.com/android/config_update/07172013-sms-blacklist.txt]
- sms_short_codes_metadata_url [http://www.gstatic.com/android/config_update/07172013-sms-metadata.txt]
- cert_pin_metadata_url [http://www.gstatic.com/android/config_update/10142013-metadata.txt]
- cert_pin_content_url [http://www.gstatic.com/android/config_update/10142013-pins.txt]
- wifi_on [1]
- assisted_gps_enabled [1]
- wifi_scan_always_enabled [1]
- device_provisioned [1]
- bugreport_in_power_menu [0]
- development_settings_enabled [1]
- adb_enabled [1]
- wifi_country_code [us]

#### `secure` namespace

- wifi_watchdog_watch_list [GoogleGuest]
- mock_location [0]
- backup_enabled [0]
- backup_transport [com.google.android.backup/.BackupTransportService]
- mount_play_not_snd [1]
- mount_ums_autostart [0]
- mount_ums_prompt [1]
- mount_ums_notify_enabled [1]
- accessibility_script_injection [0]
- accessibility_web_content_key_bindings [0x13=0x01000100; 0x14=0x01010100; 0x15=0x02000001; 0x16=0x02010001; 0x200000013=0x02000601; 0x200000014=0x02010601; 0x200000015=0x03020101; 0x200000016=0x03010201; 0x200000023=0x02000301; 0x200000024=0x02010301; 0x200000037=0x03070201; 0x200000038=0x03000701:0x03010701:0x03020701;]
- long_press_timeout [500]
- touch_exploration_enabled [0]
- speak_password [0]
- accessibility_script_injection_url [https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/javascript/android/AndroidVox_v1.js]
- lockscreen.disabled [0]
- screensaver_enabled [1]
- screensaver_activate_on_dock [1]
- screensaver_activate_on_sleep [0]
- screensaver_components [com.google.android.deskclock/com.android.deskclock.Screensaver]
- screensaver_default_component [com.google.android.deskclock/com.android.deskclock.Screensaver]
- accessibility_display_magnification_enabled [0]
- accessibility_display_magnification_scale [2.0]
- accessibility_display_magnification_auto_update [1]
- android_id [a0ef8b2a9ade982c]
- enabled_input_methods [com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.voicesearch.ime.VoiceInputMethodService]
- input_methods_subtype_history []
- selected_input_method_subtype [-1]
- selected_spell_checker [com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/com.android.inputmethod.latin.spellcheck.AndroidSpellCheckerService]
- selected_spell_checker_subtype [0]
- lock_screen_owner_info_enabled [0]
- voice_recognition_service [com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.voicesearch.serviceapi.GoogleRecognitionService]
- default_input_method [com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME]
- enabled_print_services [com.google.android.apps.cloudprint/com.google.android.apps.cloudprint.printdialog.services.CloudPrintService:com.hp.android.printservice/com.hp.android.printservice.ServiceAndroidPrint]
- enabled_on_first_boot_system_print_services [com.google.android.apps.cloudprint/com.google.android.apps.cloudprint.printdialog.services.CloudPrintService:com.hp.android.printservice/com.hp.android.printservice.ServiceAndroidPrint]
- bluetooth_name [Nexus 7]
- masterLocationPackagePrefixBlacklist [com.google.,com.semaphoremobile.zagat.android]
- serial_blacklist [827,864]
- dropbox:data_app_anr [disabled]
- dropbox:data_app_wtf [disabled]
- ssl_session_cache [file]
- pubkey_blacklist [5f3ab33d55007054bc5e3e5553cd8d8465d77c61,783333c9687df63377efceddd82efa9101913e8e]
- facelock_liveliness_recognition_threshold [2.2]
- facelock_detection_threshold [0.0]
- dropbox:data_app_crash [disabled]
- masterLocationPackagePrefixWhitelist [com.google.android.gms]
- lockscreen.options [enable_facelock]
- facelock_max_center_movement [10.0]
- bluetooth_address [AC:22:0B:A5:AF:3D]
- bluetooth_addr_valid [1]
- config_update_certificate [ *truncated base64 content* ]
- location_providers_allowed [gps,network]
- allowed_geolocation_origins [http://www.google.co.uk http:// www.google.com]
- locationPackagePrefixBlacklist []
- user_setup_complete [1]
- locationPackagePrefixWhitelist []
- last_setup_shown [eclair_1]

Comment: This was really helpful. Where could I find a complete list of possible parameters?

Comment: @SMart I found these settings by pulling the android Settings Sqlite Database file off of my target device. That DB has tables mapping to each namespace (eg global, secure) with a row per setting. If needed, I could post a dump of my copy once I am back at my desktop

Comment: That would be great. Could you also point me to the location of this database? :)

Comment: @SMart list of all keys added above

Comment: You may also want to add your package's namespace to the `secure.immersive_mode_confirmations` key.

Comment: @dtyler did you ever find any side effects?

Comment: Hi dtyler, @alexislg , i was trying your solution on a rooted phone. Can you show how you are running these commands from within the application?

Comment: @axierjhtjz do you know how to implement the solution?

Comment: @yatin I don't put this in the application. I put this in a shell script that is executed when the device boots

Comment: Hi @alexislg, thank you for replying. Could you please direct me. How to do it?

Answer (score 19):

I know this is an old question but hopefully it will help someone.  Here are two very simple calls to disable and enable the status bar that I have used before.  Can be used from the command line or executed by a Java app:

Disable:

```
service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui
```

Enable:

```
am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService
```

Comment: Thank you man! Worked on my KitKat 4.4.2. Now I'm trying to make it initialize on startup. Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: It looks like there is an init.d directory that you can use to run scripts on start-up.  Check out http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6558/how-can-i-run-a-script-on-boot for more info.

Comment: I tried this method but couldn't found the `/etc/init.d` path. I'll figure out, thanks!

Comment: It caused SystemUI to continuously crash, on my Android 6 device

Answer (score 4):

I've used this answer to hide the softkeys: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27003890/1525867

And for disabling the StatusBar (this may harm your device so do it carfully. I've ruined my device several times before I managed to do it) Tested on Asus Tinker Board, Android 6:

- Download apktool from here https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads/ and add it to `path`in your favorite way
- pull `SystemUI.apk` from your device:
  `adb pull /system/priv-app/SystemUI/SystemUI.apk` the path to `SystemUI.apk` may be different
- pull `framework-res.apk` from your device `adb pull /system/framework/framework-res.apk` the path to `framework-res.apk` may be different
- run `apktool if framework-res.apk`
- run `apktool if SystemUI.apk`
- run `apktool d SystemUI.apk`
- Open `SystemUI\res\layout\status_bar.xml` and add `android:visibility="gone"` to the top most xml element (for me it was `com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBarView`)
- run `apktool b SystemUI`
- Go to `SystemUI\original` and copy `AndroidManifest.xml` and `META-INF` to `SystemUI\build\apk\`
- run `apktool b SystemUI` again
- Go to `SystemUI\dist\` and override the device's original `SystemUI.apk` with the one at `SystemUI\dist\SystemUI.apk` with `adb push SystemUI\dist\SystemUI.apk /system/priv-app/SystemUI/SystemUI.apk`
- Restart device

Based on this thread https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2203166

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You can use `apktool b -c SystemUI` to have it automatically copy the manifest and META-INF from original APK

Comment: I do this but when replace the system.apk in android Oreo , we lost the status bar ... did we need extra work on it ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a perfect solution but a workaround here. The basic idea is to listen the system ui status changes and force navigation/status bar as invisible. It takes effect as similar as setting IMMERSIVE_STICKY mode but disappearing  navigation/status bar quicker than IMMERSIVE_STICKY.

here it is:

set system ui style in onCreate() and on onResume function, and set system ui change listener

```
    mDecroView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                      |    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    mDecroView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(this);
```

force system bar as invisible in onSystemUiVisibilityChange, setting system ui some seconds later otherwise it would take on effect(does not know exactly why, maybe system just ignores the system ui setting request when system bar showing not yet completed)

```
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "onSystemUiVisibilityChange called with visibility " + visibility);
    if((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0){
        if(null == mHandler){
            mHandler = new MyHandler();
        }
        if(null != mHandler){
            mHandler.removeMessages(MSG_HIDE_SYSTEM_BAR);
            mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_HIDE_SYSTEM_BAR, 50);
        }
        //the deccro view is not in full screen
        Log.d(TAG, "setSystemUiVisibility");
        Log.d(TAG, "current system ui is " + mDecroView.getSystemUiVisibility());


    }
}
```

then you can set system ui like this:

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch(msg.what){
        case MSG_HIDE_SYSTEM_BAR:
                           mDecroView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A great solution I found for that issue, setting each Activity `theme` & `windowSoftInputMode` to the following values :

```
<activity   android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">  <!-- theme : to set the activity to a full screen mode without a status bar(like in some games) -->
</activity>                                              <!-- windowSoftInputMode : to resize the activity so that it fits the condition of displaying a softkeyboard -->
```

for more info [refer here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

disable statusbar and navbar

```
adb shell
su 
pm disable com.android.systemui
reboot
```

enable statusbar and navbar

```
adb shell
su 
pm enable com.android.systemui
reboot
```

It works on Android 5.1.1 but the usb camera is down

Another way (my device worked without any problems)

Remove System Navigation Bar ¶
The Android System Navigation Bar is the bar at the bottom of the screen which presents the back, home, and app-switch soft-keys.

As the system navigation bar is independent from any installed Android application in particular, removing it is done in the Android OS.

To accomplish this on a rooted installed device you can set the qemu.hw.mainkeys property to 1 by editing /system/build.prop:

```
qemu.hw.mainkeys=1
```

To accomplish this at build time you would set the 'config_showNavigationBar' value to false in your device overlay (ie device/gateworks/ventana/overlay/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml):

```
<bool name="config_showNavigationBar">false</bool>
```

Note you could also make build.prop modifications at build time by adding to the PRODUCT_DEFAULT_PROPERTY_OVERRIDES or ADDITIONAL_BUILD_PROPERTIES variables which can be found in your device target configuration (ie imx6.mk and BoardConfig.mk in device/gateworks/ventana/).

Additionally, you can hide the navigation bar (and status bar) within an application by setting the SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION flag however it will pop back if the user touches anywhere on the screen.
http://trac.gateworks.com/wiki/Android/Kiosk

Comment: On some devices, "disable"/"enable" is not working anymore. Use "unhide" / "hide" instead

Answer (score 0):

For rooted devices, I use the follwing code to change visibility from within my apps.   It sets the visibility of the System UI and then reboots the device to make the setting changes actually happen. You can also use "pm "hide" com.android.systemui"... via adb, of course.

Please note that on some older devices, the command parameters were **"enable**" / **"disable"**. For newer Android versions (9+), I observed that only **"unhide"** and **"hide"** were working for me.

```
fun setSystemUiEnabled(enabled: Boolean) {
    try {
        val p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su")
        val os = DataOutputStream(p.outputStream)
        os.writeBytes(
            "pm ${if (enabled) "unhide" else "hide"} com.android.systemui\n"
        )
        os.writeBytes("reboot\n")
        os.writeBytes("exit\n")
        os.flush()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Timber.w(e, "Error while setting system-ui enabled-state to $enabled")
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Comment: attention, on HIDE you may lose your device: it will fail to boot, with error "Can't load android system bla bla". I was lucky to double restart it to restore. But it was scary. Android 9

Comment: @djdance That's really weird, that never happenend to me and I did a lot of work with rooted devices and enabling and disabling the system UI. I doubt this is caused by the hidden system UI.

Answer (score -1):

add this before : setContentView(R.layout.x);

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    // Removes title bar
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,                 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.x);
```

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried, but it does not do what I need. This only hides the bar temporarily, if the user swipes down from the top of the screen, the bar reappears, which does not work for me.

Comment: If you combine requestWindowFeature settings with a theme the user won't be able to swipe down and use bar

Comment: @portfoliobuilder, could you please provide a sample solution?