# Disable notification bar in Android 4.4 Kit-Kat

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat

I've got a full screen game that uses a swipe from the top of the screen to trigger functionality. This all worked fine until I upgraded to 4.4 Kit-Kat the other day. The game still operates perfectly well in full screen mode, but when I swipe down the notification bar appears. If I swipe down again it expands it.

Does anyone know how to disable the notification bar in Kit-Kat so that a swipe from the top of the screen does not cause the notification bar to appear?

I have the following in my code:

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

I can't use a custom ROM, permissions shouldn't be too much of an issue.

Thanks.

Comment: may be using the immersive mode ?

Comment: @njzk2 I just tried that - no luck. The documentation states "When immersive full-screen mode is enabled, your activity continues to receive all touch events. The user can reveal the system bars with an inward swipe along the region where the system bars normally appear."

Comment: here is a workaround posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371802/permanently-hide-android-status-bar/23097855#23097855