# Completely Disable/Hide Status Bar on 4.4.2

Tags: android, statusbar, android-4.4-kitkat, android-launcher

We are developing a launcher app for elderly people which has a very easy UI and we do not want to show status bar or notification drawer.

Now i tried to disable Status Bar but it seems to re-appear when i pull down from the upper side of the screen. And if i pull-down for the second time notification drawer is opened. Is there a way to completely disable Status Bar?

I checked the documentation on the following links but i think no solution is present. In API level 16 we were able to disable it completely but not in api level 19. 
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html#41

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html#nonsticky

Comment: hi, have you managed to disable notification and status bar permanently?

Comment: nop, its not possible without ROM customization.

Comment: I just managed to hide the botom button bar. If you want i can share it

Comment: sure, you could share it by responding to the question so as to everybody profits

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It hides status bar, bar with home, return buttons. I use it and it works for me on 4.4.2 AllWinner V11 tablet

Needs **ROOT**

*Use this at your own risk*

- After rooting install `SuperSU` and file manager app like `ES file explorer`.
- Grant access for `ES explorer`
- In `ES` settings check `Root explorer` then `Mount RW`
- In `/system` find build **prop.build** file
- At the end add `qemu.hw.mainkeys = 1`
- Save and exit, reboot.

This will hide the bottom bar with Return, Home, and Recent apps. No swipes or other interupts it. To show it again delete `qemu.hw.mainkeys = 1` or make it `0`

Comment: This answer is good and accurate, but only answers half of the problem. It removes the bottom bar / software keys, but does *not* remove the status bar or top-of-screen controls.

Comment: Yes @maxsilver, to hide the status bar you can create a listener when screen size changes, hide status bar immediately. Also there is one solution i didn't tested http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=37466852#post37466852

Comment: You can reverse engineer SystemUI.apk and hide the status bar. I've done it successfully, on Android 6, by following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49009629/2247427

Answer (score 1):

In `android 4.4+` you **can not hide** status bar really, **instead** you **can prevent the on click expansion** of status bar.

To hide the status bar or prevent the expansion of status bar in android 4.4+, please check the solution on below link (as solution is pretty big I am giving the link only ... :) )

[Prevent Expansion of status bar in android 4.4+ or android kitkat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984476/hide-status-bar-in-android-4-4-or-kitkat-with-fullscreen)

Answer (score 1):

You can draw some view above status bar and consume all input events. It prevent the status from expanding.

More details here:
[Permanently hide Android Status Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371802/permanently-hide-android-status-bar)

It worked for me.