# HIDE STATUS BAR ON LOCK SCREEN APP

Tags: android, android-widget, android-scroll

I am making an android lock screen app.My problem is the status bar .I writed this line on AndroidManifest.xml `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` but the users can scroll the status bar and unlock the phone without the app.So how to hide completly the status bar?

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 4.4.2, you can't hide the status bar anymore. What you can do is make it so users are unable to expand it.

The answer to this question should work for you:
[Hide status bar in android 4.4+ or kitkat with Fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984476/hide-status-bar-in-android-4-4-or-kitkat-with-fullscreen)

Comment: You won't be able to scroll until you fully close the app