# Elegant way to disable status bar?

Tags: android

Is there some good way to disable the status bar ? I have found out a solution in the answer of this question [Permanently hide Android Status Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371802/permanently-hide-android-status-bar) . But it seems to be a hacky way. Is there some normal way to disable status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Write this before your setContentView() call:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(layout);
```

This will make a fullscreen acitivity.

Comment: But it will just hide the status bar , it wont disable it .. I want to disable the status bar completely