# Making the status bar and navigation bar inaccessible

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I am developing an Android app that will run on devices that are installed for public use.  I can hide the navigation bar (bottom) and status bar (top) using flags for immersive mode, full screen, etc., and that's fine until someone:

- swipes up from the bottom of the display, showing the navigation bar, or
- swipes down from the top of the display, showing the status bar.

Is there a way, from the app, to completely disable this?  Basically I want this app to have full control over the device and to allow no option to switch to anything else.

If the solution is to modify build.prop then we can do that - we will have full control over the devices and can change them during initial setup before shipping.  But it would be good to do this by software.

Comment: I think this question has already been asked, look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371802/permanently-hide-android-status-bar

Comment: @Aenadon Yup, didn't find that one.  Thanks.