# How to stop Navbar comes when swipe up from edge in Tab?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, uinavigationbar

I want to know is there any way we can stop navbar stop showing when we swipe from the edge in the Samsung tab. I want that user navigates my app using the custom button.

I have tried this [link] ([Permanently hide Android Status Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371802/permanently-hide-android-status-bar))

can anyone try any solution to hide navbar permanently and not shows up when the app is in the foreground?

Comment: Without root, this is not possible intentionally. If it were possible you could permanently prevent the user from leaving your app.

Comment: no there is a back button inside my app from which user can leave the app .

Comment: Maybe, but nothing keeps you from removing that button.

Comment: is there a way we can disable them , mean user click on them and nothing happens .??

Comment: You can only handle the Back-Button with `onBackPressed()`. Home-Button cannot be disabled for the same reason I mentioned above.

Comment: if you find anything related to that plz let me know it's a great help